# Inner catch skipped under strange circumstances

Tags: c++, try-catch, c++17

I discovered a really strange bug in a codebase I've been working on, which I only recently was able to isolate and create something reproducible from. The bug is that the catch inside `simulate_container_init` is skipped when `throw_threshold` is even. `throw_threshold` is used in `ex_trigger` to simulate objects throwing when copied in situations such as container construction or assignment for unit testing purposes.

I originally thought this was a MSVC compiler bug(in 14.16 at the time of this writing), but after successfully reproducing it on GCC 7.1 & Clang 3.9.1(nearly the oldest of each that supports my example), I'm not sure what to make of it anymore, as the code both appears correct and functions correctly when `throw_threshold` is odd.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <type_traits>

// Used to trigger an exception after a number of constructions have occurred.
struct ex_trigger
{
private:
    static std::atomic<uint32_t> ctor_count;
    static std::atomic<uint32_t> throw_threshold;

public:
    static inline void set_throw_threshold(uint32_t value) noexcept
    {
        throw_threshold.store(value, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    std::atomic<uint32_t> value;

    inline ex_trigger(const ex_trigger& source) :
        value(source.value.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    {
        if (ctor_count.load(std::memory_order_acquire) >= 
            throw_threshold.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            throw std::logic_error("test");
        }

        ctor_count.fetch_add(1);
    }
    inline ex_trigger(uint32_t value) noexcept :
        value(value)
    {
        ctor_count.fetch_add(1);
    }
};
std::atomic<uint32_t> ex_trigger::ctor_count;
std::atomic<uint32_t> ex_trigger::throw_threshold;

// Simulates the construction of a container by copying an initializer list.
template<class T>
inline void simulate_container_ctor(std::initializer_list<T> values) {
    // Intentionally leaked to simplify this example.
    // Alignment of T is completely ignored for simplicity.
    auto sim_data = static_cast<T*>(
        ::operator new(sizeof(T) * values.size()));

    for (auto value : values) {
        if constexpr (std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>) {
            new (sim_data++) T(value);
        } else {
            try {
                new (sim_data++) T(value);
            } catch (...) {
                // Placeholder for cleanup code which is sometimes skipped.
                std::cout << "caught [inner]\n";
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // The "inner" catch handler within simulate_container_init will be skipped when the argument
    // to set_throw_threshold is even, but otherwise appears to work correctly when it's odd. Note
    // that the argument must be between 10-20 for an exception to be triggered in this example.
    ex_trigger::set_throw_threshold(11);
    try {
        simulate_container_ctor({
            ex_trigger(1),
            ex_trigger(2),
            ex_trigger(3),
            ex_trigger(4),
            ex_trigger(5),
            ex_trigger(6),
            ex_trigger(7),
            ex_trigger(8),
            ex_trigger(9),
            ex_trigger(10)
        });
    } catch (const std::logic_error&) {
        std::cout << "caught [outer]\n";
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

When `throw_threshold` is even, output is(incorrectly):

catch [outer]

When `throw_threshold` is odd, output is(as expected):

catch [inner]
catch [outer]

I've spent countless hours debugging and trying different approaches, yet it seems I'm missing something. Anything to help make sense of this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `for (auto value : values) {` copy constructing a temporary `ex_trigger` that will throw an exception outside of inner exception handler. The fix would be to iterate over references `for (auto const & value : values) {`

Comment: Sometimes what's really needed is a fresh pair of eyes. Thanks for your help.